# AWS EKS Fargate Tenant Isolation & Databases

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, architecture, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I’m looking at EKS architecture patterns for a saas multi tenant saas application and found some great resources in the AWS saas factory space. However, I have couple of questions that that I couldn’t find answers for in those resources:

The proposed application will broadly have following components:

1. Landing and Tenant Registration App (React SPA)
2. Admin UI To Manage tenants (React SPA)
3. Application UI (the product - React)
4. Core/Support Micro-services (Lambda)
5. Tenant App Micro-services(Go/Java)
6. RDS - Postgres per tenant

I’m currently leaning towards **EKS with Fargate** where namespaces used for tenant isolation.

**Questions:**

1. Is the namespaces right way to go about for tenant separation (as opposed to separate cluster/vpc per tenant)
2. Regarding tenant data (RDS) isolation, if I go with namespaces isolation, what’s the best way to go about it?

Apologies of the question isn’t clear, happy to provide further clarification of needed.

Comment: I too have the same queries, for DB we are using remote DB with JDBC connection with different schema for each tenent, Easier to maintain and manage. Regarding cluster/tenant vs namespace vs vpc/tenant still looking for correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: Could you please let me know if AWS global Accelator has capability to route the request to different ALB based on dns(base url)?

Answer: Unfortunately Global Accelerator does not have the ability to do smart routing based on URL.

Question 2: Do we require multiple AWS accelator for each customer?

Answer: That is correct.

Question 3: Do we have any other solution to access the application in-isolation for each customer?

Answer: Not in isolation it is possible to use one ALB with host header rules for your listeners. Each rule going to its own target group. This way you will control traffic by making a target group for each customer. However it does not fullfill your isolation requirement.

Question 4: Do you suggest to have different pods for each customer with routing the request to various target group based on path?

Answer: Yes that is the option I mentioned above you can use path based or host header option depending on the URL. If the URL's are completely different then host header if the URL is just different paths then path based would be best.

hope these answer help you to resolve @sheeni's queries.